# Show error message only for some input if not entered on submit in angular

Tags: angularjs

```
 <form name="someForm">  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-2">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><label for="initials" class="control-label">Initials</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="initials"
                                ng-model="searchDetails.initials"
                                class="form-control" placeholder="Initials" required />
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li><label for="surname" class="control-label">Surname</label>
                    </li>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" name="surname"
                            ng-model="searchDetails.surname"
                            class="form-control" placeholder="Surname" required />
                    </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><label>Date of Birth</label></li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="dateOfBirth"
                            ng-model="searchDetails.dateOfBirth"
                            class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-dd-mm" required />
                    </li>
                    <li><label>Identity number</label></li>
                    <li><input type="text" name="identityNumber"
                        ng-model="searchDetails.identityNumber"  class="form-control" placeholder="Identity number" required /> <span
                        class="form_error" id="idNumberMsg2"
                        data-ng-show="formName.invalid && formName.identityNumber.$error.invalidId">ID
                            number does not appear to be authentic.</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

      <span data-ng-show="!(searchDetails.initials &&   searchDetails.surname && searchDetails.dateOfBirth) ||   !searchDetails.identityNumber">
        Please search by id only or by initials, surname and  dateOfBirth
     </span>

     <div class="row">
       <input type="button" tabindex="3" id="searchClient"
                    class="button_style" value="Next" >
     </div>
    </form>
```

[image]

I would like to do a conditional check on submit that when the following three (initials, surname and dateOfBirth) have been entered and the idnumber is not entered, the form should go through without error messages and when the id number on it's own is entered and the other three is not entered, the form should go through too, else show message error. Any shed of light is highly appreciated. I'm sorry I am a newbie with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

To show the error messages, look at ng-messages and ng-message directives.
add this to your form element:

```
novalidate ng-submit="someForm.$valid && someSubmitMethod()">
```

Use ng-messages like this (it's looking at the name attribute of your input field, so input name="id" is checked below:

```
<ng-messages for="someForm.id.$error" role="alert">
      <ng-message when="required">ID is mandatory</ng-message>
</ng-messages>
```

Comment: Hi Noppey, thank you for your response, I would like to go that path but I want to let the user know which fields specifically they should enter after they submit.

Comment: Ng-messages takes care of that. It will only show the errors for fields that are actually invalid. It's not a summary though, it's shown per element.

Comment: Let me try that, thank you Noppey, if I may ask, The  submitMethod in this case will do the checking of the values as to which attributes are empty ?

Comment: Your input fields have the property required. someForm.$valid will be false if these fields are not filled. So no need to check in your submit method itself. Edit: Fixed case in nb-submit attribute.

Comment: So in this case what will happen if they fill the id number only and the others are not filled ?

Comment: Error messages will be shown for all required input fields except id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115649/discussion-between-raymond-nakampe-and-noppey).